# ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'fastapi'

Tags: fastapi

Facing error while importing in python 3.8

```
from fastapi import Request
```

throws error as
ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'fastapi'

Answer (score 1):

By default fastapi has installed version 0.47.1 on your machine. It has some bugs

you can instead install version 0.52.0
To do so

```
pip3 install fastapi==0.52.0
```

Comment: Why don't you install the latest one? And... Why are you asking your own question?

Comment: because I couldn't find a solution and I don't want others to struggle on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

More accurately, you can install version 0.51.0 (see [full release notes](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/#0510), excerpted below).

> Now `Request`, `Response`, `WebSocket`, `status` can be imported directly from `fastapi` as in `from fastapi import Response`. This is because those are frequently used, to use the request directly, to set headers and cookies, to get status codes, etc.